# Signs in a congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

Good morning everyone,

recently i've had this type of congruence:

$ \mathsf 45x \equiv 231 mod 8 $

So i divided 45 and 231 by 8 and subbed their modulo remainder, taking me to

$ \mathsf 5x \equiv 7 mod 8 $

I compute the MDC between 8 and 5 and i know by definition that it has an inverse, which is -3, coming from

$ \mathsf 1 = 8 (2) + 5(-3) $

Now, when i multiply, i don't know when the minus signs goes away. I wrote:

$ \mathsf -15x \equiv -21 mod 8 $

But i don't know how to manage the negative sign. Could someone give me a little bit of insight (theory) ? I know it has to come positive x, but i'm not sure in general when or how to do it correctly.

Comment: Hint: $-15 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$

Comment: Then  $ \mathsf x \equiv -3 mod 8 $ ? Then i change signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modular arithmetic you can add and subtract what you are modding by without changing the congruence. After all, adding $8$ is the same as adding $0$ in this context. Thus we have $-3=8-3=5\mod 8$. You could also note that $-15=16-15=1\mod 8$ and $-21=24-21=3\mod 8$.

Until you get more comfortable with modular arithmetic it wouldn't be a bad idea to just keep on adding what you are modding out by until everything is positive.

Comment: So basically, the x is always positive no matter what, and if i get a negative b number, i just have to add it until it is between 0 and mod?

Comment: Yep, that us true.